# Multi threading not executing Tasks simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I wrote a python code for my project that stores file name of files on the SFTP server in a list and does the same for local directory and compares the 2 lists and then download the uncommon files. code takes its server credentials from a separate text file of format

CONTENTS OF TEXT FILE (config9.txt)

```
127.0.0.1,username,password,log22.txt,/new45,C:\Users\udit\Desktop\ftp2\bob16
```

my program executed one by one for different IP's. I wanted it to run it parallely for all IP's using multithreading. I modified my code but it still executes it one by one. Whats the error in it?

```
import os
import pysftp
import csv
import socket
from stat import S_IMODE, S_ISDIR, S_ISREG
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import os.path
import shutil
import fileinput
import lock

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

def mainprocess():
    with open("config9.txt", "r") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            print(row)
            IP=row[0]
            myUsername=row[1]
            myPassword=row[2]
            txtfile=row[3]
            remotepath=row[4]
            localpath=row[5]

            with pysftp.Connection(host=IP, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
                r = str(socket.gethostbyaddr(IP))
                print("connection successful with " + r)


                def get_file2(sftp, remotedir):
                    result = []
                    for entry in sftp.listdir_attr(remotedir):
                        remotepath = remotedir + "/" + entry.filename
                        mode = entry.st_mode
                        if S_ISDIR(mode):
                            result += get_file2(sftp, remotepath)
                        elif S_ISREG(mode):
                            if (time.time() - entry.st_mtime) // (24 * 3600) > 0:
                                result.append(entry.filename)

                    return result


                remote_path = remotepath
                d = get_file2(sftp, remote_path)


                def process():
                    myName = []
                    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
                        for name in f.readlines():
                            while '\n' in name:
                                name = name.replace('\n', '')
                                myName.append(name)
                    print(myName)
                    print(len(myName))

                    import os

                    filtered_list = [string for string in d if string not in myName]
                    print("filtered list:", filtered_list)
                    print(len(filtered_list))

                    local_path =localpath

                    def compare_files(sftp, remotedir, remotefile, localdir, preserve_mtime=True):
                        remotepath = remotedir + "/" + remotefile
                        localpath = os.path.join(localdir, remotefile)
                        mode = sftp.stat(remotepath).st_mode
                        if S_ISDIR(mode):
                            try:
                                os.mkdir(localpath, mode=777)
                            except OSError:
                                pass
                            compare_files(sftp, remotepath, localpath, preserve_mtime)
                        elif S_ISREG(mode):
                            sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, preserve_mtime=True)

                    for file in filtered_list:
                        compare_files(sftp, remote_path, file, local_path, preserve_mtime=False)

                    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
                        for item in filtered_list:
                            f.write("%s\n" % item)


                filename=txtfile
                try:
                    file = open(filename, 'r')
                    process()
                except IOError:
                    file = open(filename, 'w')
                    process()



t=time.time()

t1=threading.Thread(target=mainprocess(),args=())
t1.start()

t1.join()
```

Comment: could you please add the content of `config9.txt` to the question?

Comment: You only create one thread at the bottom of the script and then have that thread do the work of the entire script. You need to break your code in chunks and then make threads for each one.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim can u give example please?.  beginner in python

Comment: when you create the `Thread`, you pass `target=mainprocess()` which is equivalent to `target=None` since `mainprocess` doesn't return anything. to call `mainprocess` via the thread, you have to pass the function itself as target like this: `t1 = Thread(target=mainprocess)`

Comment: Aside from that issue, why would you even expect more than one IP to be processed at the same time? There's only the main thread and the `mainprocess` thread running (and the main thread is blocked while waiting for the former to finish via the `t1.join()` call).

Comment: @martineau I just want that if there are 10 IP's in config file it should connect to 10 IP's when the code run and start downloading from 10 servers simultaneously,if it happens one by one it will take more time.

Comment: udit: Yes, I understand what you want to do. I'm just saying that the code in your question doesn't do concurrent downloading from multiple servers due to the way it is written. The downloads are processed sequentially all within the `mainprocess()` thread, whereas you would need to have multiple download threads all running at the same time to accomplish the goal.

Comment: @martineau it would be of great help if you look at my code and help me modify it to achieve my purpose. any suggestion would be nice

Comment: Sorry, in my opinion the changes required are too extensive and involved to be done via this forum, so all I will do is recommendation that you look into using a [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) to create separate threads for downloading the files. Also here's a good youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zinZmE3Ogk&feature=youtu.be) by Raymond Hettinger on the subject of concurrency in Python.

Comment: @martineau if I have to use multiprocessing instead,then also the code has to be heavily changed?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, because the problem is with how `mainprocessing()` currently works — namely by sequentially reading the data from the csv file for each row and then downloading (and further processing the data in) it. It is the latter parst of that need to be spawned into a separate thread or process (so it doesn't block until the it's finished).

Comment: I will get back to you after trying

Comment: I would suggest initially simplifying the problem to just doing a maximum number simultaneous ftp downloads at once (i.e. don't worry about only doing uncommon files). Also note that `concurrent.futures` can also do multiprocessing and often only requires relatively minor changes to do one or the other. Good luck!

Comment: i tried but it keeps on failing